# How to convert .properties to linux env export file

Tags: python, linux, shell, ansible, devops

We have properties file as follows and used for java, need to convert the same to linux varaibles including substitues on right side of =.

```
installation.location=/tmp
ClusterName=demo
product.names=app1,app2,app3
version=2018
logical.host.name=test.domain.com

app1.installation.location=$[installation.location]/app1
app2.installation.location=$[installation.location]/app2
app3.installation.location=$[installation.location]/app3
appserver.hostname=test.domain.com
ant.home=/3rdparty/apache-ant-1.10.1
java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
abc.application.name=app1
appserver.hostname=
ucl.standalone=true
app1.application.name=$[abc.application.name]
app1.external.hostname=$[appserver.hostname]
app1.external.port=30001
app2.external.hostname=$[appserver.hostname]
```

I have the following code, it will convert and create the   setEnv.sh file but unable to change/convert installation.location, appserver.hostname etc on right side of the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)

cut -d= -f 1 env.properties  | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | tr '.-' '_' > $tmp1
cut -d= -f 2 env.properties | tr '[]' '{}' > $tmp2

paste -d= $tmp1 $tmp2 > setEnv.sh.temp

sed -e "s/\r//g" -e '/^=/d' -e '/^#/d' setEnv.sh.temp > setEnv.sh
sed -i 's/ *= */=/' setEnv.sh

#sed -i '/^(\s*#|$)/!s/^/export /' setEnv.sh
sed -i '/^#/!s/^/export /' setEnv.sh
#sed -i 's/^/export /' setEnv.sh

rm $tmp1 $tmp2
rm setEnv.sh.temp
```

I get below results but not accuare

```
export INSTALLATION_LOCATION=/tmp
export CLUSTERNAME=demo
export PRODUCT_NAMES=app1,app2,app3
export VERSION=2018
export LOGICAL_HOST_NAME=test.domain.com
export APP1_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${installation.location}/app1
export APP2_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${installation.location}/app2
export APP3_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${installation.location}/app3
export APPSERVER_HOSTNAME=test.domain.com
export ANT_HOME=/3rdparty/apache-ant-1.10.1
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Comment: how can i achieve the desired output? If any python logic that works is also fine

Comment: Do you really __need__ all those shell variables to be in upper case?  [Generally, user shell variables should be lower or mixed case to avoid accidentally interfering with shell or utility settings.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an awk command which makes the changes that seem to be required for your sample input file:

```
$ awk -F= '/=/{gsub(/\./, "_", $1); $1="export " toupper($1); gsub(/\[/, "{"); gsub(/\]/, "}"); gsub(/\r/, "")} 1' OFS== env.properties
export INSTALLATION_LOCATION=/tmp
export CLUSTERNAME=demo
export PRODUCT_NAMES=app1,app2,app3
export VERSION=2018
export LOGICAL_HOST_NAME=test.domain.com

export APP1_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${installation.location}/app1
export APP2_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${installation.location}/app2
export APP3_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${installation.location}/app3
export APPSERVER_HOSTNAME=test.domain.com
export ANT_HOME=/3rdparty/apache-ant-1.10.1
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export ABC_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
export APPSERVER_HOSTNAME=
export UCL_STANDALONE=true
export APP1_APPLICATION_NAME=${abc.application.name}
export APP1_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME=${appserver.hostname}
export APP1_EXTERNAL_PORT=30001
export APP2_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME=${appserver.hostname}
```

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their command spread out over multiple lines:

```
awk -F= '
/=/{
    gsub(/\./, "_", $1)
    $1="export " toupper($1)
    gsub(/\[/, "{")
    gsub(/\]/, "}")
    gsub(/\r/, "")
} 1' OFS== env.properties
```

#### How it works

- `-F=` tells awk to use `=` as the field separator.
- `/=/{...}` tells awk see if the current line contains `=` and, if so, perform the commands in braces on that line.  Those commands are:

  - `gsub(/\./, "_", $1)` tells awk to replace periods with underlines in the first field (variable name).
  - `$1="export " toupper($1)` tells awk to translate the variable name to upper case.
  - `gsub(/\[/, "{")` and `gsub(/\]/, "}")` tell awk to replace `[` and `]` with `{` and `}`, respectively.
  - `gsub(/\r/, "")` tells awk to remove any carriage return characters.
- `1` tells awk to print the line.
- `OFS==` tells awk to use `=` as the field separator on output.
- `env.properties` tells awk which file to operate on.

#### Enhanced version

This adds some additional features that were in your code but not needed for the sample input:

```
awk -F= '
/^=/ {
    next
}
/^[^#]/ && /=/{
    gsub(/\./, "_", $1)
    $1="export " toupper($1)
    gsub(/\[/, "{")
    gsub(/\]/, "}")
    gsub(/\r/, "")
    sub(/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/, "=")
} 1' OFS== env.properties
```

#### Additional Features

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/(\[[^]]*)\./\1_/; ta; s/\[[^]]*\]/\U&/' env.properties | awk -F= '/=/{gsub(/\./, "_", $1); $1="export " toupper($1); gsub(/\[/, "{"); gsub(/\]/, "}"); gsub(/\r/, "")} 1' OFS==
export INSTALLATION_LOCATION=/tmp
export CLUSTERNAME=demo
export PRODUCT_NAMES=app1,app2,app3
export VERSION=2018
export LOGICAL_HOST_NAME=test.domain.com

export APP1_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${INSTALLATION_LOCATION}/app1
export APP2_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${INSTALLATION_LOCATION}/app2
export APP3_INSTALLATION_LOCATION=${INSTALLATION_LOCATION}/app3
export APPSERVER_HOSTNAME=test.domain.com
export ANT_HOME=/3rdparty/apache-ant-1.10.1
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export ABC_APPLICATION_NAME=app1
export APPSERVER_HOSTNAME=
export UCL_STANDALONE=true
export APP1_APPLICATION_NAME=${ABC_APPLICATION_NAME}
export APP1_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME=${APPSERVER_HOSTNAME}
export APP1_EXTERNAL_PORT=30001
export APP2_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME=${APPSERVER_HOSTNAME}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works great. May be i was not clear in my initial post, I want to also convert the value assigned to variable. For example,  i have the "installation.location=/tmp" and export app1.installation.location=$[installation.location]/app1, where $[installation.location] needs to be replaced with "${INSTALLATION_LOCATION}/app1" as well, otherwise this varibale assignment become invalid in linux export. There may some other like this as follows

Comment: Thank you so much. It works great. May be i was not clear in my initial post, I want to also convert the value assigned to variable. For example,  i have the "installation.location=/tmp" and export app1.installation.location=$[installation.location]/app1, where $[installation.location] needs to be replaced with "${INSTALLATION_LOCATION}/app1" as well, otherwise this varibale assignment become invalid in linux export. There may some other values as follows   abc.application.name=app1
app1.application.name=$[abc.application.name]. And yes, changing to upper case is really not that important.

Comment: John, the solution works really great but can you please help modify second fiels i.e $ such that it works to change . to _ within { } paranthesis and also text inside that to uppercase if possible. I tried adding "gsub(/\./, "_", $2)" but it change for all fields including for hostnames which is not correct. I only need to change for text within ${...} for example, from ${installation.location} to $INSTALLATION_LOCATION} on every field of $2.

Comment: @rangred For that extra capitalization and `.`-->`_`, try the new code at the end of the answer.

Comment: It works like a gem, you are the star. Thank you so much.